# how to delete duplicate records in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue with finding and deleting duplicate records, I have a table with IDs called *CallDetailRecordID* which I need to scan and delete records, the reason there are duplicates is that I'm exporting data to special arching engine works with ***MySQL*** and it doesn't support indexing.

I tried using "`Select DISTINCT`" but it dosn't work, is there is another way? I'm  hoping I can create a store procedure and have it run weekly to perform clean up.

your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why is the DISTINCT not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table LIKE table    
INSERT INTO tmp_table (SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY CallDetailRecordID)
RENAME table TO old_table
RENAME tmp_table to table
```

Drop the old table if you want, add a `LOCK TABLES` statement at the beginning to avoid lost inserts.